# How do I print a specifc character pattern using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to print a pattern using Python but I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
 # The Pattern I am trying to create is as follows:
    *******
    ******
    *****
    ****
    ***
    **
    *

#Using the following code:

    base = 8

    for rows in range(base):
        for columns in range(7,1,-1): 
            print('*',end='')
        print()
```

Comment: change `range(7,1,-1)` to `range(7,rows,-1)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for columns in range(7,1,-1)` always prints 6 times. Maybe you meant `for columns in range(7,rows,-1)`? However this is easier:

```
for i in range(7,0,-1):
    print('*' * i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This answer did what I needed. Sorry I am such a newb to Python!

Comment: Just realized that my answer won't print a blank line. If you want that, change the 0 to a -1.

Comment: Very clever and slick solution

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for i in range(8):
    print("*" * i)
```

That will actually print in wrong order, sorry, overlooked that.

```
for i in range(8,0,-1):
    print("*" * i)
```

Comment: This will print it in reverse order

Comment: Yeah I just realised he wanted it in reversed order, not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using *"reverse order"* slicing:

```
base = 8
for i in range(1, base)[::-1]:
    print('*' * i)
```

The output:

```
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

## solution 1

```
for i in range(4,0,-1):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print('#',end=" ")
    print()
```

## solution 2

```
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4-i):
        print('#',end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to use Nested Loop You can easily do it with a simple for loop**

```
base = 8
for rows in range(base,0,-1):
     print("*"*rows)
```